# Vim vs command is creating duplicate output in second pane

Tags: vim

Whenever I create a vertical split in VIM using the :vs command, the newly created panel is a duplicate of the first, and it updates both panels in real-time as I type.

How can I turn this behaviour off and make it revert to opening a second independent panel?

Comment: What would an independent panel do? Contain the text present at the time of the split instead of actually having a file open inside it?

Comment: No, I just want to open another blank document in the second pane that I can edit independently.

Comment: Do you mean `:vnew`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what's supposed to happen. If you don't want what a command does, use another command that does what you want.

From `:help :vsplit`:

```
Like :split, but split vertically.
```

From `:help :split`:

```
Split current window in two. The result is two viewports on the same file.
```

If you scroll down a bit you can find `:help :vnew`:

```
Like :new, but split vertically.
```

Which leads you to `:help :new`:

```
Create a new window and start editing an empty file in it.
```

So… what you want is `:vnew`.